# Pig Group By Addition

Tags: apache-pig

I have data files split by "|" so I'm using below code.

```
  RAW_LOG = LOAD 'logs.log' USING TextLoader as (line:chararray);
  splt = foreach RAW_LOG  generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|'));   
  id_vals = foreach splt generate $4 as uid, $8 as site_id , $9 as dsid , $6 as amt;
```

I want to SUM(amt) of each site_id, i have tried group by but didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to group by site_id and sum up value of amt for each group?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want end result to be two columns site_id and sum of amt for that site_id.

You can directly load pipe separated file using PigStorage, no need to load and then split. It will be good to provide schema definition, though you can access elements using $.

Here is the code -

```
RAW_LOG = LOAD 'logs.log' USING PigStorage('|') as (//YOUR SCHEMA DEFINITION);
SITE_GRP = group RAW_LOG  by site_id;
SITE_SUM = foreach SITE_GRP generate group, SUM(RAW_LOG.amt);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting "Problem working with Doubles".
I tried setting float as data type to amt touple and it dones't have any characters.

Comment: Can you share your sample data and schema definition, With double as well I am getting correct results.

Comment: I got it working by adding.
(float)amt cast inside foreach.
Thanks a ton mate.